# How to import data into my React component and use as javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, import, components

I'm building a name generator web app with React and need to import a [custom array](https://github.com/markohanesian/armenian-names/blob/master/src/components/NameData.js) with id, name, meaning, gender into [my component](https://github.com/markohanesian/armenian-names/blob/master/src/components/Generator.js) in order to build a randomizer. I am importing the file as NameData, and attempting to parse the list for names via `const RandomName = NameData.name` but nothing is displaying when I attempt to call the object like this `{name}`.

How can I correctly import the array from my names file and create JS objects for ids, names, meanings, and gender?

#### custom array (NameData.js) code:

```
// temporary list of 4 names
export default [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Astghik',
    sex: 'female',
    meaning: '"little star". Derived from the Armenian word "astgh" meaning "star" and the suffix "ig" meaning "little." Famous real-life people named Astghik Astghik in song, story & screen. Astghik is the Armenian goddess of fertility and love.',
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Lusine',
    sex: 'female',
    meaning: 'Lusine is a feminine given name derives from the Armenian “Lusin (Լուսին)”, meaning “moon”. The ancient Armenians, like the Latins, possessed two different names for the moon.'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Hayk',
    sex: 'male',
    meaning: 'Hayk the Great (Armenian: Հայկ, Armenian pronunciation: [hajk]), or The Great Hayk, also known as Hayk Nahapet (Հայկ Նահապետ, Armenian pronunciation: [hajk nahapɛt], Hayk the "head of family" or patriarch), is the legendary patriarch and founder of the Armenian nation.'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Razmik',
    sex: 'male',
    meaning: 'little soldier/fighter'
  }
];
```

#### component (Generator.js) code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// name data
import NameData from "./NameData.js";
// shuffle button via material-ui icons
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";
// material-ui 
import { Typography, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import '../App.css';


// converting name data into objects
const RandomName = NameData.name;

function Generator() {
    const [startingName, newName] = useState('name');

    return (
        <>
             <Typography variant="h1" component="h2" gutterBottom>
                {startingName}
            </Typography>
            <Grid id="generator-buttons-container">
                <IconButton
                    aria-label="favorite name"
                    // onClick={() =>
                    // }
                >
                    <SvgIcon id="generator-favorite-icon">
                        <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5 2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c0 3.78 3.4 6.86 8.55 11.54L12 21.35l1.45-1.32C18.6 15.36 22 12.28 22 8.5 22 5.42 19.58 3 16.5 3zm-4.4 15.55l-.1.1-.1-.1C7.14 14.24 4 11.39 4 8.5 4 6.5 5.5 5 7.5 5c1.54 0 3.04.99 3.57 2.36h1.87C13.46 5.99 14.96 5 16.5 5c2 0 3.5 1.5 3.5 3.5 0 2.89-3.14 5.74-7.9 10.05z"/>
                    </SvgIcon>
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton
                    aria-label="generate new name"
                    onClick={() =>
                        newName(RandomName[Math.floor(Math.random() * RandomName.length)])
                    }
                >
                    <SvgIcon id="generator-shuffle-icon">
                        <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M10.59 9.17L5.41 4 4 5.41l5.17 5.17 1.42-1.41zM14.5 4l2.04 2.04L4 18.59 5.41 20 17.96 7.46 20 9.5V4h-5.5zm.33 9.41l-1.41 1.41 3.13 3.13L14.5 20H20v-5.5l-2.04 2.04-3.13-3.13z"/>            
                    </SvgIcon>
                </IconButton>
            </Grid>
            
        </>
    );
};

export default Generator;
```

Comment: `NameData` is an array therefore `NameData.name` is undefined. If you want to extract all names you should do: `const RandomName = NameData.map(item => item.name);`

Comment: Yes, you NameData isn't a single object, and you cannot access name directly. First you need to select an object inside it, and then select the name attribute of that object.